# Unable to locate imported document at 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/ETFrameworkFault.xsd

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I'm using the below code to get client -

```
    ETConfiguration configuration = new ETConfiguration();
    configuration.setClientId(clientId);
    configuration.setClientSecret(clientSecret);

    ETClient client = new ETClient(configuration);
```

I've added below jars in classpath -

```
fuel-java-1.0.3.jar;
cxf-api-2.7.3.jar;
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws.jar;
cxf-rt-core-2.7.2.jar;
XmlSchema-1.3.2.jar;
gson-2.2.2.jar;
apache-logging-log4j.jar
```

error :

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException:
>   org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to
>   create service.   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.(ServiceImpl.java:149)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:65)
>     at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:77)     at
>   com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal.PartnerAPI.(PartnerAPI.java:49)
>     at
>   com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapConnection.(ETSoapConnection.java:88)
>     at
>   com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapConnection.(ETSoapConnection.java:154)
>     at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.(ETClient.java:156)   at
>   com.test.ExactTargetSdk.main(ExactTargetSdk.java:29) Caused by:
>   org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to
>   create service.   at
>   org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:205)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.(ServiceImpl.java:147)    ...
>   7 more Caused by: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException:
>   Unable to locate imported document at
>   'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/ETFrameworkFault.xsd', relative to
>   'jar:file:/Users/satyajit/Documents/Sumanta/ExactTarget/libs/fuel-java-1.0.3.jar!/etframework.wsdl'.
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.catalog.CatalogXmlSchemaURIResolver.resolveEntity(CatalogXmlSchemaURIResolver.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:1872)

Please advise whats wrong here

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sumanta, did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue and can't see anything obvious to fix it in Google

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any solution?

Comment: I created maven project and after it was fine....before I had created simple java project which was not able to download dependency

Answer (score 1):

I was already using Maven and still had problems. Having looked at this again, the "release" version 1.0.3 is broken.

If you check out the repository and build locally, all seems to be OK.

For reference, the dependency to add is:

`<dependency>
  <groupId>com.exacttarget</groupId>
  <artifactId>fuelsdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0-pre1</version>
</dependency>`